# check authenticate user in middleware using laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm trying to create a middleware in Laravel 5.6 that checks if the user is authenticate or not. My middleware :

```
checklogin.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class checklogin
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return redirect('/welcome');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }


}
```

I added this in kernel.php in protected $routeMiddleware :

```
'checklogin' => \App\Http\Middleware\checklogin::class,
```

I also added it on router :

```
Route::get('/login','loginController@index');
Route::post('/welcome','loginController@store')->middleware('checklogin');
```

and also used

```
use App\Http\Middleware\checklogin;
```

My loginController is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
session_start();

class loginController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('/login');
    }

     public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $name = $request->name;
        $result = DB::table('tbl_login')
                 ->where('name',$name)
                 ->first();
                 if ($result) {
                     Session::put('name',$result->name);
                     Session::put('id',$result->id);
                     return Redirect::to('/welcome');
                 }
                 else{
                    Session::put('messege','invalid email or password');
                    return Redirect::to('/login');
                 }
    }
```

And my login.blade.php is :

```
<p class="alert-danger">
    <?php 
        $messege = Session::get('messege');
        if ($messege) {
            echo "$messege";
            Session::put('messege',null);
        }
    ?>
</p>

<form method="POST" action="{{url('/welcome')}}">                        
@csrf


    <label for="name" >Name</label>
         <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" required autofocus>                                           
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                login
            </button>

</form>
```

But it shows this error message :

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

I am new to laravel. I am just started learning. I dont know where is the problem. Please help!

Comment: why are you creating your own middleware for checking authentication. laravel has built it `auth` middleware. You also don't need to start session manually in controller `session_start`, laravel has `web` middleware that do it automatically. For Auth check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#introduction

Answer (score 1):

## Laravel 8

### If you don't want to use 'auth' middleware

#### 'auth' middleware involves user to be logged in. If he isn't logged in the routing won't handle. Sometimes you would have to check if user is logged in public route.

You can do it like this:

In your controller you have to add construct with your own middleware.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $this->user = $request->user('api');

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

The most important part here is

```
$request->user('api');
```

If your routing is public (without any middleware for restriction) it will be using all information accessible publicly, so there won't be session, token, etc.
Normal usage of **$request->user();** won't work.

Luckily **$request->user()** can take an argument

```
 /**
 * Get the user making the request.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function user($guard = null)
{
    return call_user_func($this->getUserResolver(), $guard);
}
```

so if you do **$request->user('api')**, it will retrieve the user using the api guard, because those informations are accessible in 'api' guard.

Now in your code you can check if $this->user is null (null it will be not logged user, object it will be logged user).

Source: Answer #1, point 3rd here https://www.py4u.net/discuss/32099

Answer (score 0):

it seems ok but check this line

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
   return redirect('/login');
}
```

you cant redirect **POST** route, you have to redirect only **GET** route
you can use `/login` or any other routes

or create another route in **GET**

```
Route::get('/welcome','loginController@home')->middleware('checklogin');

public function home()
{
    return view('/home');
}
```